# How do I generate a mathematical formula for the following question and answer?

Tags: word-problem

I have a legal issue and need to express an example and solution as a mathematical formula for clarity purposes and I don't know how to do that. I'd very much appreciate if someone could show me how to do this please.

Example:
I have a pool of units called the Reserve Unit Pool

I have a second pool of units, called the Subset that I need to divide into equal parts and ensure they correspond with the number of units in the Reserve Unit Pool

So, if the Reserve Unit Pool is 1,000 and the Subset pool is 50, the answer is that each of the 1,000 Reserve Units will have a corresponding 0.05 Subset unit.

How do I express both the above example and also the solution as a mathematical formula?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you take each part and multiply it with the number of units in subset, you should get the number of units in reserve.  part=Subset/Reserve